# Spark-Scala Unable to infer schema (Defer input path validation into DataSource)

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

[SPARK-26039](https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SPARK-26039)

While loading empty orc folder. Anyways to bypass this.

```
val df = spark.read.format("orc").load(orcFolderPath)

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for ORC. It must be specified manually.;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:185)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:185)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:184)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:373)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
  ... 49 elided
```

Getting this error may be orc reader trying to infer schema but i want to bypass this special case when somehow in repository blank folder came up but has to be checked.

```
try {
    spark.read.format("orc").load(path)
    } catch {
        case ex: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException => {
        null
            }
    }
```

Tried by this way to catch exception. Any other way would be helpful

Comment: Put this code in a separate function. If the function catches this exception, change a class level variable value or flag.

Comment: @Nikhil...i dont want to use try catch. But if there is empty folder there would always be exception...so want another way of doing it..

Answer (score 0):

got one more solution seems like...this is also not best one...

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}

  def pathStatus(path: String): Boolean = {
      val config: Configuration = new Configuration()
      val fs: FileSystem = FileSystem.get(config)
    if (fs.globStatus(new Path(path)) == null) {
      false
    } else {
      true
    }
  }
```